# Required não funciona

Tags: html, html5, tabela-html

Gostaria que os campos não fossem enviados em branco, então tentei usar o required..porém não está funcionado. Qual o motivo?

```html
<form action="https:/----Site---" method="POST">
  <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Dj0000001qrSu">
  <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://-----/?msg=ok">
  <input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="Formulário Site">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Nome:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Empresa:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefone:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="Mensagem/Comentários:" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: tente colocar required="required"

Comment: Esse código esta dentro de um form ? Como esta sendo realizada o envio da requisição ? Poderia publicar todo o form ?

Comment: fiz a edição para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Thiago, não funcionou.

Comment: O que não funciona? Ele consegue enviar o form mesmo com valor em branco? é isso? Ou não envia nada do form?

Comment: Testei o seu código e aparentemente funcionou, qual o resultado ? Ele pelo menos aponta que o campo não esta preenchido ?

Comment: Consegue enviar mesmo o form estando em branco

Comment: Mayllon ele não aponta que o campo está em branco, simplesmente envia a mensagem normalmente.

Comment: Se quiser deixar deixar seu código mais enxuto, em vez de repetir `required="required"` em todos os campos do form, se você usa jQuery na sua página, basta colocar uma linha de script para que todos os campos tenham `required`: `$("form *").attr("required","required");`.

Comment: @Dvdsamm o problema já foi resolvido na resposta, o navegador do AP não tinha suporte ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efetuei o teste e está funcionando pra mim. O "required" foi um recurso adicionado ao HTML5 teu navegador precisa ter suporte para tal. Efetue um teste no chrome por exemplo.

Você pode usar o site: http://html5test.com/ para averiguar se seu navegador é adequado.

```html
<form action="https:/----Site---" method="POST">
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Dj0000001qrSu">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://-----/?msg=ok">
    <input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="Formulário Site">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Nome:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" maxlength="250" required="required"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Empresa:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefone:" maxlength="250" required="required" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <textarea name="description" placeholder="Mensagem/Comentários:" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Bacana, realmente o codigo estava certo, Porem no meu navegador eu consigo enviar em branco. E meu pareceiro aqui na frente não..que estranho

Answer (score 0):

O atributo REQUIRED foi inserido com o HTML5 e só funciona em algumas versões dos navegadores.

Possivelmente você está testando em um navegador que não da suporte, segue a lista dos navegadores que aceitam e validam o atributo REQUIRED

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Estou usando a versão mais recente do Google Chrome.

Comment: Esse código aí que você colocou no STACK está funcionando sem problemas, tem mais código que você não colocou?

Comment: Realmente agora está funcionado. Já foi resolvido.